# Java - getting data from website using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

How get selected data (screen - Total shoots) from website using jsoup?

[image: HTML structure]

Updated code (still not returning expected value):

```
try {
    final Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/#/football/market/1.127737590").get();

    for (Element statItem : document.select("div#stat-item")) {
        for (Element child : statItem.children()) {
            System.out.println(child.attr("class") + " = " + child.text());
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Checking the site with disabled JavaScript in a browser gives you a hint for your problem: no content is displayed, so jsoup (has no JavaScript support) is not enough to scrape this page. Look into headless browsers (HtmlUnit, PhantomJS, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the title try:

```
try {
    final Document document = Jsoup.connect("www...").get();
    for (Element row : document.select("div#si-title")) {
        System.out.println(row.text());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you need more values of the `stat-item` try this:

```
try {
    final Document document = Jsoup.connect("www...").get();
    for (Element statItem : document.select("div#stat-item")) {
        for (Element child : statItem.children()) {
            System.out.println(child.attr("class") +" = " +child.text());   
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```